# Docker Compose Django, Webpack and building static files

Tags: node.js, django, docker, webpack, docker-compose

I’m trying to figure it out how to build static files using Node and Webpack during production build and mount them as volume which is going to be served for Django webapp and used for Django collectstatic.

I’ve got all services separated to its own containers and each has own Dockerfile.

Current problem is that i can’t access generated access files generated by webpack inside Django app.  Question is, can I achieve this using separate Dockerfiles for Node and Django, or shall this be done in one Dockerfile?

## Node Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR ./code
COPY ./package.json ./yarn.lock /code/
COPY ./webpack.base.config.js ./webpack.prod.config.js /code/
RUN yarn install --production
ADD static /code/static/
RUN yarn run prod
```

## Python app Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.2-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
  && apk add \
    bash \
    curl \
    build-base \
    postgresql-dev \
    postgresql-client \
    libpq \
    tzdata

    WORKDIR /code
    ADD requirements.txt /code
    RUN pip install --upgrade pip
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
    ADD ./ /code
    ENV TZ=Europe/London

    EXPOSE 8000
```

## Docker Compose production

```
version: '3'

services:

  frontend:
    build: docker/services/node
    volumes:
      - static_files:/code/static

  webapp:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - ./public:/code/public/
      - static_files:/code/static
    command: ["./docker/scripts/wait-for-it.sh", "database:5432", "--", "./docker/services/webapp/run-prod.sh"]
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - database

  database:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    expose:
      - "5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  nginx:
    build: docker/services/nginx
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./public:/www/public/
    depends_on:
      - webapp
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://0.0.0.0:8000"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_files:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a multi stage build for this. In your case the first stage would generate your static files, while the second stage would package your python app and copy the static files from the node.js docker image. The resulting image will only contain python dependencies.

Here is the multistage dockerfile, documentation can be found here https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds

```
# static files build stage
FROM node:alpine as static # named as static for easy reference
WORKDIR /code
COPY ./package.json ./yarn.lock /code/
COPY ./webpack.base.config.js ./webpack.prod.config.js /code/
RUN yarn install --production
ADD static /code/static/
RUN yarn run prod

# python app package stage 
FROM python:3.6.2-alpine as final # named as final because it's final :)
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
  && apk add \
    bash \
    curl \
    build-base \
    postgresql-dev \
    postgresql-client \
    libpq \
    tzdata

WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD ./ /code
# This next command has access to the file contents of the previous stage. 
# Ideally you should rewrite the paths to copy the static files from where they have been generated to where they should end up
# The 'from' clause is used to reference the first build stage 
COPY --from=static /code/static/path/to/static/files /code/desired/location


ENV TZ=Europe/London

EXPOSE 8000
```

You can then use this single image in your docker-compose file.